# Bootstrap -- Issues with a responsive sidemenu that is connected to the main menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have attempted to adjust a [responsive sidemenu snippet](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/responsive-sidebar-menu), so that I could have both the main bootstrap menu and a sidemenu that collapses on small screens.

I somehow managed to make all the necessary changes, except for two:

1. Force the sidemenu to scroll on large screens, even if it's placed inside a fixed container (specifically, the nav element).
2. Add a border below main menu, one that reaches the edges of the browser window. This one seems to be ridiculously hard for me to achieve, I even attempted to add new divs or use pseudo-element selectors (::after in particular).

If you have any suggestions, please make them --even if they have nothing to do with those two issues. 
Thank you very much

[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/YYkxvr4LB1)

Comment: Please post a working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: @vanburen I have already done so, it's the "Demo" link above the tags

Answer (score 0):

2) Border below main menu. 
Try to add:

```
#navbar-collapse-1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}
```

Comment: I have already attempted to do it this way, but that border doesn't reach the edges of the window and ends up looking a bit weird. I have attempted to solve this by using the class container-fluid for the menu, but things started falling apart so I switched back. Nonetheless, I voted, I thank you.